# How do you mysqldump specific table(s) with UTF8 Encoding?

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, xampp

When I am making a backup using utf8 / utf8mb4 encode, my table query returns with unrecognized characters.

Here's the backup command I am using in C#:

```
"-u{0} -p{1} -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 dbname tablename"
```

output:

```
    -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.24, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dbname
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.24

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `tablename`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `Sno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ShopItemcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Itemname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tablename`
--

LOCK TABLES `tablename` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tablename` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES (992,'JPBC20','à®œà¯€à®©à¯à®¸à¯(à®ªà¯‚à®Ÿà¯à®•à®Ÿà¯)à®šà®¿20'),(993,'JPBC22','à®œà¯€à®©à¯à®¸à¯(à®ªà¯‚à®Ÿà¯à®•à®Ÿà¯)à®šà®¿22'),(994,'JPBC24','à®œà¯€à®©à¯à®¸à¯(à®ªà¯‚à®Ÿà¯à®•à®Ÿà¯)à®šà®¿24');
```

But, when I am take backup in Xampp means the characters returns good.

Comment: I have written a C# Native Library, you can give it a try. It is an alternative to MySqlDump: https://github.com/adriancs2/MySqlBackup.Net

Answer (score 1):

Tamil?  Starting with `ஜீன...`?  You have Mojibake.  That is, somewhere in the path, something was declared `latin1` instead of `utf8`.

Read about Mojibake here: [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .  See if its suggestions provide the solution.

There is a chance that it is "double-encoded".  `SELECT HEX(Itemname) ...`; `ஜீன` will be

`E0AE9C E0AF80 E0AEA9` in correctly stored utf8, or
`C3A0 C2AE C593 C3A0 C2AF E282AC C3A0 C2AE C2A9` if double-encoded.

To fix the data, if you can't easily reload, see
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: ya right Tamil. thanks for the details about encoding.

Answer (score 0):

**I succeed as follows:**

I export my table as latin1 charset, It returns my query well, but only the other Language values are returned as double encoded. When I import the query with utf8 charset, it returns double encoded data as original.

Like this,

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --default-character-set=latin1

mysql -uuser -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8
```